# Do alternative dimensions depends on the world seed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

We have a new world on our 1.0 minecraft server in which we just created a nether portal.

We started exploring the nether to gather some materials, but didn't manage to find a nether fortress or structures to get some nether brick.

I was thinking of deleting the nether folder of the world and let the server regenerate it from scratch, hoping for more luck during the generation process.

However, before doing such, that question came to my mind : 'Is the nether dimension tied to the world seed ?'.

If so, deleting the world may be useless, and we need to explore further to find a nether fortress.

Does anyone have information on how the alternative dimensions are generated relative to the world seed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the Nether is generated the same way as other terrain (in fact it's just a special biome). It uses your world seed to generate it, so re-generating will not affect the layout of it (although there may be slight changes, such as the position of mushrooms, but I'm guessing that this doesn't bother you too much).

Comment: What about spawn point? That could radically affect the experience in the nether, considering how big it is. Will the spawn remain the same since the portal linking to the nether is not moved?

Comment: Yes, the nether and 'overworld' are aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Build another nether portal in the overworld. But before you do that, get one of your friends (or get a plugin that allows world switching) to break the nether portal in the nether. Then go through the newly created nether portal in the overworld. It should create a portal in the nether relative to your overworld position, giving you a new area of nether to explore.